# merging and counting similar strings

Tags: r, string

I have a data with three columns like

```
Inputdf<-structure(list(df1 = structure(c(4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("P61160,P61158,O15143,O15144,O15145,P59998,O15511", 
"P78537,Q6QNY1,Q6QNY0", "Q06323,Q9UL46", "Q92793,Q09472,Q9Y6Q9,Q92831", 
"Q92828,Q13227,O15379,O75376,O60907,Q9BZK7"), class = "factor"), 
    df2 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("", "P61158,O15143,O15144", 
    "Q06323,Q9UL46", "Q6QNY0", "Q92828"), class = "factor"), 
    df3 = structure(c(5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "O15511", 
    "Q06323,Q9UL46", "Q6QNY0", "Q92793,Q09472"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("df1", 
"df2", "df3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I am trying to find similar strings in this data for example

in `df1`, I have the first row I have `Q92793,Q09472,Q9Y6Q9,Q92831`
then I look at df2 and df3 and see if any of these members are in there then in this example, I make the following data

```
df1 df2 df3 Numberdf1      df2     df3
1   0   1   4              0      Q92793,Q09472
```

df1 1 means the first row of df1
df2 0 means it did not have any similarity
df3 1, means the first row of df3 has similarity with df1 row 1
Numberdf1, it is the count of strings separated by a `,`which is 4
df2 is 0 because there was not any similar string accords df2
df3 is Q92793,Q09472 which paste the string which were similar in here

a desire output looks like below

```
out<- structure(list(df1 = 1:5, df2 = c(0L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L), df3 = c(1L, 
0L, 2L, 4L, 3L), Numberdf1 = c(4L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 2L), df2.1 = structure(c(1L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "P61158,O15143,O15144", "Q06323,Q9UL46", 
"Q6QNY0", "Q92828"), class = "factor"), df3.1 = structure(c(5L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "O15511", "Q06323,Q9UL46", "Q6QNY0", 
"Q92793,Q09472"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("df1", "df2", 
"df3", "Numberdf1", "df2.1", "df3.1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

The below function does not work , for example, use this data as input

```
Inputdf1<- structure(list(df1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Q06323,Q9UL46", 
"Q92793,Q09472,Q9Y6Q9,Q92831", "Q92828,Q13227,O15379,O75376,O60907,Q9BZK7"
), class = "factor"), df2 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("P25788,P25789", 
"Q92828, O60907, O75376", "Q9UL46, Q06323"), class = "factor"), 
    df3 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Q92831, Q92793, Q09472", 
    "Q9BZK7, Q92828, O75376, O60907", "Q9UL46, Q06323"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("df1", 
"df2", "df3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Could you check the `out`?  Are those values correct?  In the second row of `out`, how did you get df2.1 as  `Q92828` when the value of `df2` is `P61158,O15143,O15144` and similarly for the last row

Comment: @akrun the row of df1 is important, it might be similar with row 2 or 3 or 10 of df2. in that case the second row of df1 had a similar string in the third row of df2. is it now clear?

Answer (score 1):

This works for your example:

```
# First convert factors to strings to lists
Inputdf[] = lapply(Inputdf, as.character)
Inputdf[] = lapply(Inputdf, function(col) sapply(col, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x,','))))

not.empty = function(x) length(x) > 0
out = data.frame()

for (r in 1:nrow(Inputdf)) {
  df2.intersect = lapply(Inputdf$df2, intersect, Inputdf$df1[[r]])
  df3.intersect = lapply(Inputdf$df3, intersect, Inputdf$df1[[r]])

  out[r, 'df1'] = r
  out[r, 'df2'] = Position(not.empty, df2.intersect, nomatch=0)
  out[r, 'df3'] = Position(not.empty, df3.intersect, nomatch=0)
  out[r, 'Numberdf1'] = length(Inputdf$df1[[r]])
  out[r, 'df2.1'] = paste(Find(not.empty, df2.intersect, nomatch=0), collapse=',')
  out[r, 'df3.1'] = paste(Find(not.empty, df3.intersect, nomatch=0), collapse=',')
}

out
#   df1 df2 df3 Numberdf1                df2.1         df3.1
# 1   1   0   1         4                    0 Q92793,Q09472
# 2   2   3   0         6               Q92828             0
# 3   3   4   2         3               Q6QNY0        Q6QNY0
# 4   4   2   4         7 P61158,O15143,O15144        O15511
# 5   5   1   3         2        Q06323,Q9UL46 Q06323,Q9UL46
```

Note: `Find` and `Position` identify the *first* match only. If there are potentially multiple matches, use `which`.

**EDIT**

Version accounting for multiple matches

```
Inputdf[] = lapply(Inputdf, as.character)
Inputdf[] = lapply(Inputdf, function(col) sapply(col, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x,',\\s*'))))

not.empty = function(x) length(x) > 0
out = data.frame()

for (r in 1:nrow(Inputdf)) {
  df2.intersect = lapply(Inputdf$df2, intersect, Inputdf$df1[[r]])
  df3.intersect = lapply(Inputdf$df3, intersect, Inputdf$df1[[r]])

  out[r, 'df1'] = r
  out[r, 'df2'] = paste(which(sapply(df2.intersect, not.empty)), collapse=',')
  out[r, 'df3'] = paste(which(sapply(df3.intersect, not.empty)), collapse=',')
  out[r, 'Numberdf1'] = length(Inputdf$df1[[r]])
  out[r, 'df2.1'] = paste(unique(unlist(df2.intersect)), collapse=',')
  out[r, 'df3.1'] = paste(unique(unlist(df3.intersect)), collapse=',')
}

out[out==""] = "0"
```

Comment: there is multiple similarity, would it be possible to change to that way because on real data, it does not give correct answers

Comment: I posted another example above to show you that it does not work!! I don't know where the problem is

Comment: @nik In the new example there are extra spaces separating items ("A, B" vs "A,B")

Comment: Change the `strsplit` arg to `',\\s*'`

Comment: can you help me to make the which ?