# Pivot table of concatenated string in r

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
mydata<- data.frame(Factors= c("a,b" , "c,d" , "a,c"), Valu = c ("2,3" , "7,8" , "9,1"))



   Factors Valu
1     a,b  2,3
2     c,d  7,8
3     a,c  9,1
```

and I wish to convert to the following which has all the values that happend with a factor:

## My ideal output

```
a   b  c  d
2   2  7  7
3   3  8  8
9      9
1      1
```

I need a pivot table. However I need to prepare the data and then use `melt` and `dcast` have my desirable output: one of fail tries for preparing data is :

```
mydata2 <- cSplit(mydata, c("Factors","Valu") , ",", "long")
```

But they lose their connections.

Comment: With `tidyr`, melting to long is not hard: `mydata %>% separate_rows(Factors, Valu)`. Spreading back to wide is harder, though, because there's no inherent row order. You could do something like `mydata %>% rownames_to_column('row') %>% separate_rows(Factors, Valu) %>% spread(Factors, Valu)`, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a couple of `*apply`s, `strsplit` and `grep`

```
## convert columns to characters so you can use strsplit
mydata$Factors <- as.character(mydata$Factors)
mydata$Valu <- as.character(mydata$Valu)


## get all the unique factor values by splitting them 
f <- unique(unlist(strsplit(unique(mydata$Factors), split = ",")))

## filter 'mydata' by using 'grep' to search for each individual factor value
## (using sapply for one at a time)
l <- sapply(f, function(x) mydata[grep(x, mydata$Factors), "Valu"])
```

This gives a list, where each element is named by the 'Factor' value, and it contains all the 'Valu' values associated with it

```
l
# $a
# [1] "2,3" "9,1"
# 
# $b
# [1] "2,3"
# 
# $c
# [1] "7,8" "9,1"
# 
# $d
# [1] "7,8"
```

Another `lapply` on this list will split the 'Valu's

```
result <- lapply(l, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, split = ",")))

result
# $a
# [1] "2" "3" "9" "1"
# 
# $b
# [1] "2" "3"
# 
# $c
# [1] "7" "8" "9" "1"
# 
# $d
# [1] "7" "8"
```

---

**Edit**

To get the result in a data.frame, you can make each list element the same length (by filling with `NA`), then call `data.frame` on the result

```
## the number of rows required for each column
maxLength <- max(sapply(result, length))

## append 'NA's to list with fewer than maxLenght lements
result <- data.frame(sapply(result, function(x) c(x, rep(NA, maxLength - length(x))) ))
result
#     a    b c    d
#   1 2    2 7    7
#   2 3    3 8    8
#   3 9 <NA> 9 <NA>
#   4 1 <NA> 1 <NA>
```

---

**Edit**

In response to the comment, if you have 'similar' strings, you can make your `grep` regex explicit by using `( )` (see [any regex cheatsheet](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) for explanations)

```
mydata<- data.frame(Factors= c("a,b" , "c,d" , "a,c", "bo,ao"), Valu = c ("2,3" , "7,8" , "9,1", "x,y"))

mydata$Factors <- as.character(mydata$Factors)
mydata$Valu <- as.character(mydata$Valu)

f <- unique(unlist(strsplit(unique(mydata$Factors), split = ",")))

## filter 'mydata' by using 'grep' to search for each individual factor value
## (using sapply for one at a time)
l <- sapply(f, function(x) mydata[grep(paste0("(",x,")"), mydata$Factors), "Valu"])
```

Comment: Thank you it is awesome. I tried to avoid using `grep` since I have many factors with some similarities. For instance, I have `b` and `bo` . Do you have any suggestion that help me avoid using `grep`

Comment: @MFR - I wouldn't be hasty with the 'tick' - you're bound to get a couple more answers... :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is an one-line code with `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
with(cSplit(cSplit(mydata, 1, ",", "long"), 2, ",", "long"), split(Valu, Factors))
#$a
#[1] 2 3 9 1

#$b
#[1] 2 3

#$c
#[1] 7 8 9 1

#$d
#[1] 7 8
```

---

If we need a `data.table/data.frame`, use `dcast` to convert the 'long' format to 'wide'.

```
dcast(cSplit(cSplit(mydata, 1, ",", "long"), 2, ",", "long"), 
           rowid(Factors)~Factors, value.var="Valu")[, Factors := NULL][]
#   a  b c  d
#1: 2  2 7  7
#2: 3  3 8  8
#3: 9 NA 9 NA
#4: 1 NA 1 NA
```

NOTE: `splitstackshape` loads the `data.table`.  Here, we used `data.table_1.10.0`.  The `dcast` from `data.table` is also very [fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079280/how-can-i-speed-a-function-in-tidyr-up/41079419#41079419)

Comment: thank you so much. Would you please guide me how to convert to a data frame ? because it has different number of rows it gives me an error @akrun

Comment: @MFR Updated the post to convert it to a data.table.  If you need to convert to `data.frame`, use `setDF(res)` where `res <-dcast(...`

Answer (score 4):

Another base R attempt:

```
# character conversion first
mydata[] <- lapply(mydata, as.character)

long <- do.call(rbind, 
  do.call(Map, c(expand.grid, lapply(mydata, strsplit, ","), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
)
split(long$Valu, long$Factors)

#$a
#[1] "2" "3" "9" "1"
#
#$b
#[1] "2" "3"
#
#$c
#[1] "7" "8" "9" "1"
#
#$d
#[1] "7" "8"
```

Comment: @thelatemail thank you, it works perfectly. However, I wish to convert the result to a dataframe. It seems impossible because it has different number of rows. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @MFR - my advice would be to work with the `long` dataset instead, which is usually a better storage and analysis format. You could always use `reshape` or `dcast` or something similar to "reshape long to wide" (search that exact string here at Stackoverflow for literally hundreds of relevant answers.

Answer (score 4):

I misunderstood in my comment above; if you want every `Factor` to match every `Valu`, you need to separate the columns independently to get the combinations. If you add indices to spread by, it's not too bad:

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata %>% 
    separate_rows(Factors) %>% separate_rows(Valu, convert = TRUE) %>%
    # add indices to give row order when spreading 
    group_by(Factors) %>% mutate(i = row_number()) %>%
    spread(Factors, Valu) %>% 
    select(-i)    # clean up extra column

## # A tibble: 4 × 4
##       a     b     c     d
## * <int> <int> <int> <int>
## 1     2     2     7     7
## 2     3     3     8     8
## 3     9    NA     9    NA
## 4     1    NA     1    NA
```

Comment: Nice answer, and it matches what OP requested perfectly. On a tangential-at-best note, I would however say there is nothing "tidy" about a data.frame full of NA values.

Comment: @thelatemail Agreed; the long form makes way more sense here.

Comment: Thank you @alistaire , the idea is brilliant. However, the `spread(Factors, Valu)` doesn't work efficiently and can not deal with a relatively big data.

Comment: a. I'd advise using the long for you'll get from the two `separate_rows` calls for the reasons already mentioned: there's no relation between observations in your rows, and you'll have lots of useless `NA` values. b. What's "relatively big"? I've generally found it to scale to half a million observations without any extra measures. That said, how far you're spreading will have an impact as well; if you're creating thousands of columns, it will also be slow. data.table is a practical alternative, though the syntax is different. You could try combining the two with dtplyr, if you like.